# @Where with @SecondaryTable does not work with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, informix

There is a one-to-many relationship in my model, where the child entity is stored in two tables.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child1")
@SecondaryTable(name = "child2", pkJoinColumns = {
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id1", referencedColumnName = "id1"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id2", referencedColumnName = "id2")})
@Where(clause = "col1 is not null and col2 is not null")
@Data
@Immutable
public class Child implements Serializable {...}
```

`Child` entity is fetched eagerly together with `Parent` entity. Problem lies within `@Where` clause, which should reference columns from two tables: `col1` is in table `child1` and `col2` is in `child2`. This throws the following error:

```
ERROR 12333 --- [nio-8183-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column (col2) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).
java.sql.SQLException: null
...
```

1. Using only: `@Where(clause = "col1 is not null")` gives propper mapping and results in no error.
2. Using `@Where(clause = "child1.col1 is not null and child2.col2 is not null")` gives the following error:

   ```
   Column (child1) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).
   ```

How can I make `@Where` work with two tables or is there any workaround?

There are some requirements though:

1. I'm using informix as an underlying database and have read-only access.
2. I know, that it can be solved by native SQL or even JPQL / criteria API and so on, but doing so would make me rewrite a lot of core. I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the [HHH-4246](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4246) issue.

A workaround would be to replace the `@SecondaryTable` with a `@OneToOne` association using [`@MapsId`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

This way, the `child2` table becomes the `Child2` entity for which you can use `@Where` or `@Filter`.